# How to separate NSString with multiple commas?

Tags: ios, nsstring

Am having this nsstring

```
NSString * countryStr = @"6023117,159,en_US,Seychelles,SC,Seychelles,6023185,95,en_US,Kuwait,KW,Kuwait,6023182,172,en_US,Swaziland,SZ,Swaziland,6023185,157,en_US,Saudi Arabia,SA,Saudi Arabia,6023182,177,en_US,Tanzania,TZ,Tanzania,6023185,179,en_US,Togo,TG,Togo,6023185,87,en_US,Cote d'Ivoire,CI,Cote d'Ivoire";
```

now i want to display only the countries which are suffixed by "en_US".
can anybody tell me how to split that string to get the countries.

I did like this

```
NSError * error;
NSString* imageName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CountryList" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString * countrStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:imageName encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];
NSArray * dfd = [countrStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"en_US"];
for(int i=0;i<dfd.count;i++)
{
    NSString * nama = [dfd objectAtIndex:1];
    NSArray * djk = [nama componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSString * aksjd = [djk objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this;

```
NSString * countryStr = @"6023117,159,en_US,Seychelles,SC,Seychelles,6023185,95,en_US,Kuwait,KW,Kuwait,6023182,172,en_US,Swaziland,SZ,Swaziland,6023185,157,en_US,Saudi Arabia,SA,Saudi Arabia,6023182,177,en_US,Tanzania,TZ,Tanzania,6023185,179,en_US,Togo,TG,Togo,6023185,87,en_US,Cote d'Ivoire,CI,Cote d'Ivoire";

    NSArray * arrData = [countryStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];;//[countryStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"en_US"];

    for(int i=0;i<arrData.count;i++)
    {
        NSString * str = [arrData objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([str isEqualToString:@"en_US"] && i<arrData.count-1)
        {
            NSString* countryName = [arrData objectAtIndex:i+1];

            NSLog(@"countryName %@", countryName);
        }
    }
```

But you should manage data in your file, loading from resource.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it is

```
 NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@, %@, %@", var1, var2, var3];
```

Excuse the formatting/syntax errors. Typing this via iPhone. But if there is any errors, look up stringWithFormat: in iOS documents on the apple developer page for corrections.

Comment: Why do you have the string so cluttered in the first place? Try splitting it into an array, then query the array and place the query into the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your string seems to have the following pattern:

1. A number,
2. An other number,
3. The country language code,
4. The name,
5. A short code,
6. An (other) name.

So what you can do is to use a loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dfd.count; i += 6) {
  if ( dfd[i + 2] ) } // check the country code at index i + 2
   // Do something
   }
 }
```